# Apply the elements of an array to a functions javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new in Javascript and I'm try to apply a function to each element of an array and then return the output recursively. Can you help me? I have the loop to go thought the element of the array but I don't know the signature to apply to them the function. Here is my part of the code:

```
function mapReduce(f, a, seed) {
     for(i = 0; i != a.length; i++){

    }
}
```

Where f is the function, a is the array and seed is a value that I have to add at the end (I have to sum the output and then add the seed parameter). Hope you can help me. Sorry if the question could result stupid

```
var itemize = function(x) {
    if(x == undefined){
        return undefined
    } else {
    var str = "<li>";
    var fin = "</li>";
    return str + x + fin;
    }
 };
```

The test is:

```
equal(mapReduce(itemize, ["A","B","C"]), "<.li>A<./li><.li>B<./li><.li>C<./li>" ,    "MapReduce(itemize, ['A','B','C']) should yield '<.li>A<./li><.li>B<./li><.li>C<./li>'")
```

For the map reduced I did something like this:

```
 function mapReduce(f, a, seed) {
 for(i = 0; i != a.length; i++){
    if(seed != undefined){
        if(a != undefined) {
            seed = seed + f(a[i]);
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    } else {
        var d = "";
        d = d + f(a[i]);
    }

}
return seed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want your `mapReduce` function to be equivalent to

```
a.map(f).reduce(function(prev, item) {
    return item == undefined ? prev : prev + item;
}, seed == undefined ? "" : seed)
```

If you want to combine this behaviour in a dedicated function, remove the intermediate array and make the for-loop explicit you would write

```
function mapCombineString(f, a, seed) {
    if (!f || !a) return; // throw new TypeError() would be appropriate
    if (seed == undefined)
        seed = "";
    for (var i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
        var item = f(a[i], i, a);
        if (item != undefined)
            seed = seed + f(a[i]);
    }
    return seed;
}
```

Comment: it's enough to say "amazing"? Yes it works perfectly. I use a stupid intermediate array. Thanks for all Bergi